# How the unbounded following works in SQL server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

[The Table "Cric_Team" looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYVnk.png)

When I execute the below query in SQL Server 2012, the 'unbounded following' is not calculating the sum upto last row of that partition. But, as per the definition, it should calculate upto last row from the current row.

> SELECT Cric_Id,Cric_First_Name,Cric_Last_Name,Cric_Role ,Runs,Centuries ,Fifty AS Fifties,Ducks,SUM(Ducks) OVER ( PARTITION BY Cric_Role ORDER BY Ducks  RANGE BETWEEN current row AND unbounded following ) AS Total_Ducks FROM Cric_Team

[The Screenshot of table after executing the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUsjf.png)

Answer (score 0):

How about using a descending sort instead?  Do this do what you want?

```
SELECT Cric_Id, Cric_First_Name, Cric_Last_Name, Cric_Role, Runs,
       Centuries, Fifty AS Fifties, Ducks,
       SUM(Ducks) OVER ( PARTITION BY Cric_Role ORDER BY Ducks DESC) AS Total_Ducks  
FROM Cric_Team;
```

Comment: Without adding 'DESC' also, it is sorted in descending order. Don't know what's happening.